# SSL server: Unable to get local issuer certificate (Let's Encrypt)

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

As the title says I'm having some problems with my https connection, it was working perfectly but now (2 weeks after) I was installing the Jetpack plug-in on my wordpress site when I got an `IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

I went to my website and the https connection was working perfectly (I can still access it) and the certificate details on the browser said that it was still valid:

[Certificate description on Safari and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xDV.png)

But `openssl s_client -connect tiferrei.com:443` gives:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /CN=tiferrei.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /CN=tiferrei.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /CN=tiferrei.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=tiferrei.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X1

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=tiferrei.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2253 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

Some more info:

**Domain:** tiferrei.com

**Issuer:** Let's Encrypt Authority

**Webserver:** Apache2

**Database:** MySQL

**OS:** Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

I'm sorry this probably a super easy and simple question and I tried Google but I couldn't find anything that worked, I even searched throw the WordPress forums.

Thanks in advance,
Tiferei

Comment: Exactly where did you see that error?

Comment: Wow that was quick! I saw it when I was reinstalling the Jetpack wordpress plugin, and after install I have to connect it to my wordpress account, this usually leads to a login page in wordpress.com but I got this error right above the "Connect to wordpress" button.

Comment: OK, so it's Wordpress.com can't connect to you? The first thing I would do is [fix the SSL misconfigurations](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tiferrei.com&hideResults=on) of your site. If you installed Let's Encrypt it should have [configured Apache correctly](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/blob/master/letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/options-ssl-apache.conf), but it appears something went wrong there.

Comment: At first I also thought it was something specific, maybe I wasn't allowing wordpress on my firewall or something like that, (btw self-hosted with port forwarding) but the I ran that command and I saw that it wasn't just wordpress...

Comment: Also, I'm a complete beginner on this so how exactly do I apply the suggested improvements?

Comment: Got the disable SSLv3 one but have no idea how to de the others...

Comment: Solved the SSL misconfigurations, A+ grade  But I keep getting the same error.